# How do I get the number of characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string

`mb_strlen` only gives number of bytes, and it is not what I wanted.

It should work with multibyte characters.

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: `mb_substr` gives you a substring of a given multi-byte string - this has nothing to do with the length of the string. Use `mb_strlen` as others have suggested.

Comment: byte size -> ```strlen()``` ex: ```strlen('a₹')``` -> ```4```. character count -> ```mb_strlen()``` ex: ```mb_strlen('a₹', "UTF-8")``` -> ```2```. Note: ```mb_strlen()``` is disabled by default in php.

Answer (score 13):

```
mb_strlen($text, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 11):

You may make use of [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

Comment: It's correct, perhaps PHP doesn't recognize your string as Multibyte string? Try something like this: mb_strlen($your_multibyte_string,$encoding) where encoding should be something like "UTF-8" or "UTF-16"

Comment: How do you use mb_strlen, and what encoding is used for the string you're testing ?

Answer (score 6):

[`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) with [`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

Answer (score 2):

**strlen():** Returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

```
$name = "Perú"; // With accent mark
echo strlen($name); // Display 5, because "ú" require 2 bytes.

$name = "Peru"; // Without accent mark
echo strlen($name); // Display 4
```

**mb_strlen():** Returns the number of characters in a string having character encoding. A multi-byte character is counted as 1.

```
$name = "Perú"; // With accent mark
echo mb_strlen($name); // Display 4, because "ú" is counted as 1.

$name = "Peru"; // Without accent mark
echo mb_strlen($name); // Display 4
```

**iconv_strlen():** Returns the character count of a string, as an integer.

```
$name = "Perú"; // With accent mark
echo iconv_strlen($name); // Display 4.

$name = "Peru"; // Without accent mark
echo iconv_strlen($name); // Display 4
```

Answer (score 0):

[mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) the string being **measured** for length.

```
<?php
$str = 'abcdef';
echo strlen($str); // 6

$str = ' ab cd ';
echo strlen($str); // 7
?>
```

Directly from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UTF-8 encoding, step through all bytes in the string and count the characters which have the eighth bit *not* set.

This solution does not need the *mb* extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php), but I use just plain old [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) myself...

Comment: Characters vs. bytes. Why would it work as intended? Can you elaborate in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: OK, *RandyMorris* seems to have left the building. Can somebody else chime in?