# Counting characters in a string in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How can I get the exact length of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914779/how-can-i-get-the-exact-length-of-a-string-in-php)

What is the best way in PHP to count how many characters are in a string?

I did a web search and couldn't seem to find anything.

Comment: `strlen()` didn't show up? Are you wanting to count only ASCII characters or possibly multi-byte encoded characters?

Comment: I just did a Google search using your exact title. Here is what it returned. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: I didn't think about clicking on the php pages.

Comment: There is also *[How do I get the number of characters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728472/)*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php):

```
$count = mb_strlen( $string );
```

You could also use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), but you asked for the best way ;)

Comment: If your program only ever handled ASCII and the mb extension wasn't installed, `strlen()` might end up being the best way :)

Comment: Awh man it's been so long since I've read up on core php. I totally forgot about the strlen function. Thanks you all.

Comment: [Here is nice comment about strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#54906)

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby And I didn't believe you're referring to strlen, I thought you where asking about [count_chars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

Comment: Good stock knowledge up up.