# "strlen" does not give the exact number of characters

Tags: php, wordpress, strlen

I have a WordPress Template with a loop of articles where I want to show the characters that every articles have. I do it this way:

```
<?php $length = strlen( utf8_decode( get_the_content() ) ); echo $length; ?>
```

But for example it shows "1848" characters for an article that in reality only has "1594" characters.

EDIT: Not perfect but comes closer:

```
$length = mb_strlen( wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content));
```

Comment: Might be caused by multi-byte chars, consider using: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: When use "mb_strlen" it shows me less characters but still too much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of characters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728472/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-characters-in-php)

Comment: @herrfischer, kindly add the raw text/content that you get with the ``get_the_content()`` method.

Comment: `var_dump(get_the_content(), utf8_decode( get_the_content() ));` gives what?

Comment: It gives 2x the content but one is not UTF encoded. The encoded stuff has more characters than the not encoded with the "�"-placeholders.

Comment: Have you taken this into account? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/: _"An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content() does not pass the content through the the_content filter. This means that get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things."_

Comment: Yes, I use "get_the_content".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

**first step:**
Add this code in the `functions.php` file.

```
function mb_str_word_count($string)
{
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $words = mb_split(' ', $string);
    return count($words);
}
```

**Second step:**
Use this code in the loop.

```
$length = mb_str_word_count(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_content())));
```

Here, using the `strip_tags` and `strip_shortcodes` functions, we remove the html tags and shortcodes to show us the number of real words.

Comment: This counts the words, not the characters.

Comment: @herrfischer oh It's true, I didn't see the question correctly.